# Hibernate 5.1.0.Final format_sql doesn't work with SchemaExport

Tags: hibernate, groovy

I use the code below to test with SchemaExport.

```
def metadata = new MetadataSources(new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().build())
    .addAnnotatedClass(DummyEntity)
    .buildMetadata()
def schemaExport = new SchemaExport()
schemaExport.create(EnumSet.of(TargetType.DATABASE), metadata)
```

Hibernate read file **hibernate.properties** from classpath

```
hibernate.dialect = <my_dialect>
hibernate.connection.driver_class = <my_driver>
hibernate.connection.url = <my_url>
hibernate.connection.username = <my_username>
hibernate.connection.password = <my_password>
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = validate
hibernate.show_sql = true
hibernate.format_sql = true    <------- NO EFFECT!
```

I'm not sure if it is a bug in Hibernate 5.1.0.Final or other?

Answer (score 0):

The property "hibernate.format_sql" is not meant for SQL in SchemaExport. It is for formatting the console output only.
Feel free to request a new feature with the Hibernate team.